# Electrodynamics and induced EMF question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics

> A very long straight wire carries a current I. A plane rectangular coil of high resistance, with sides of length $a$ and $b$, is coplanar with the wire. One of the sides of length $a$ is parallel to the wire and a distance $D$ from it; the opposite side is further from the wire. The coil is moving at a speed $v$ in its own plane and away from the wire.
>
> (a) Find the e.m.f. induced in the coil.
>
> (b) Let R be the resistance of the coil. Calculate the force needed to move the coil with speed v as described, and show that the mechanical power used to move it is equal to the rate at which heat is generated in the coil.

I have included my workings/thoughts.

I know that i first have to calculate the magnetic field of the wire:
$$B(y)=\mu_0 I/2πy $$
Then the emf,
$$\mathcal{E}=-\frac{dφ(B)}{dt}= -\frac{d}{dt} \int_D^{D+b}B\cdot ds = -\frac{d}{dt}(a\cdot \int_D^{D+b} B\cdot dy)$$

I have been given the answer of
$$\mathcal{E}=\frac{\mu_0Ivab}{2\pi D\left(D+b\right)}$$

Do I have to perameterise the integral? If so does anyone have a guide on how to do this?

What I am having trouble with is the intermediate step getting from the integral to the above answer.

I know that $P_{mech}=F.v$ and that $P_{heat}= v^2/R = \mathcal{E}/R$, but I do not know how to calculate the force on the coil.